# what is different between cp1252 excel and cp1252 delimeted file when exporting oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

why do i export data from oracle sql developer to excel with encoding 1252 successfully.But it is wrong data when into delimeted file with encoding 1252

Comment: Windows-1252 or CP-1252 (code page 1252) is a single-byte character encoding of the Latin alphabet, used by default in the legacy components of Microsoft Windows for English and many European languages such Spanish or French. what character set do you have in your database ?

Comment: character set is 'AL32UTF8'

Comment: if you have a multicode characterset as UTF-8, and you try to export to an unicode character you will have issues